# How to hide Empty in perspective view Blender 2.8?

Tags: image

In 2.79 with background images, it was easy to only allow them to be shown in ortho view, but in 2.8 I'm using empties as reference images, and I can't find how to hide them in perspective view and only show in ortho, like the old version.  Where can I find that option, assuming it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First press the related number on the numpad to select the view of your preference, then import the ImageReference Empty.
Then on its image properties deselect (uncheck) the "Display Perspective"

[image]

Comment: Is this option only available when you add the image, it can't be changed after the fact?

Comment: I dont know really, this is how it works for me :/ probably ther must be a way after you do the import to fix the perspective culling

Comment: Oh okay I found it, it was right where you said, I was looking in the wrong place.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah I see you meant the proper tab in properties, yes it is there ;) :D